# Can I use mineral spirits to clean off stripper prior to water based stain, if I clean off the mineral spirits?

Tags: staining

I’m completely new to all of this but have researched as much as I can in the last couple months. Please bear with me if I sound uninformed. I’m definitely willing to learn.

I got a cheap mango wood desk/console table that appeared to have been finished with poly-something over the bare wood. I like the desk and thought it a good piece for learning as I go before trying other projects. It’s not so important to me that I can’t make mistakes.

I stripped the clear finish off using Citristrip. I know that’s far from the best choice but I’m in an apartment and was concerned about fumes. The Citristrip seems to have done a decent job of removing whatever the clear finish was, but I was interrupted before I was satisfied, and I know there are some spots of it left. I also think just because it’s Citristrip, the wood really needs to be prepared with something to get all residue off.

On the inside of the desk there are two areas where there was no finish at all where I sanded to 180, and tried out some water based stain. I’d like to try staining the whole piece with this and then follow with a finish.

That’s the background for my question. I think mineral spirits are usually recommended to clean off strippers as well as to highlight where some finish might remain, but mineral spirits are not for use before a water based stain. Would I be okay to use something else—maybe denatured alcohol? Or use the mineral spirits, then wash that off when I’m done? I realize Citristrip is not a preferred stripper, and I don’t want to use it again due to the mess it created, but for now, this is what I’ve got.

Answer (score 2):

> The citristrip seems to have done a decent job of removing whatever the clear finish was, but I was interrupted before I was satisfied, and I know there are some spots of it left.

In addition to there being some Citristrip residue you know you need to deal with, it is vital to check there's no finish residue as you refer to later. It seems to be one of the least-mentioned bits of stripping advice but it's a cornerstone of finish removal that one should never expect stripper (even one much stronger/more efficient than Citristrip) to get every trace of finish off in a single application. You might get lucky and one treatment does it, but never *expect* it (even on pieces where the finish appears to be thin and is in poor condition — worn through in areas, weakened by age, cleaning, light exposure, all of the above.)

> I think mineral spirits are usually recommended to clean off strippers

But what do Citristrip's instructions say to use?

As always with generic advice it can be of little help when it comes to specifics. And I know/know of many users who would not use mineral spirits *regardless of the stripper used*<sup>1</sup>.

> as well as to highlight where some finish might remain

Yup, but actually any clear liquid will do the same — water, isopropanol, vodka (not kidding), denatured alcohol (UK: methylated spirits), xylene or naphtha, acetone or lacquer thinner (UK: cellulose thinners). Someone out there will make use of one of these for this purpose, depending on personal preference and sometimes just what is most conveniently at hand.

> but mineral spirits are not for use before a water based stain.

You *can* use mineral spirits before a waterbased stain, but you will have an easier time if you use something else. In addition to not having to worry about beading, you'll be able to proceed much faster so win-win.

> denatured alcohol?

Yes that would have been what I would have suggested you try first anyway since it will probably work well to lift Citristrip residue without being overly toxic, plus it's relatively cheap and widely available.

Once you're sure you've removed all the residue you'll probably need to sand a bit (this is normal) and it would be best to do this fairly uniformly over the entire piece.

And after that I recommend you also wipe down with water. You can do this as a final check for finish residue, but when using a waterbased stain it's advisable to dampen the wood beforehand to pre-raise the grain anyway<sup>2</sup>.

---

> I don’t want to use it again due to the mess it created

Not that I particularly want to defend Citristrip (I have specific reservations about it, and other similar strippers) but to be fair *all* stripping is inherently a messy, dirty business. However, if good procedures are adopted<sup>3</sup> dealing with the mess can be relatively painless..... at least on flat surfaces, carved work and detailed spindles/turnings are a different story LOL

---

<sup>1</sup> For various reasons, e.g. because of the smell, preferring to use something that evaporates faster, wanting to use something that stands a chance of further dissolving any remaining traces of finish clinging to the wood.

<sup>2</sup> You then *lightly* sand before staining; you're looking to sand off the raised grain only, that's it. Resist the temptation to sand any more than that!

<sup>3</sup> Including not letting the stripper dry on the surface, wetting it again if it did dry out anywhere, scraping off the bulk of the sludge and using stiff brushes for inside corners and other tight spots.

Comment: Thank you so much. I have been reading your posts here a lot and am so grateful! This has become the only site I regularly use for information, and I specifically look for your answers. 

The directions on the Citristrip label for removing:

Comment: “ Use a paint stripper wash to loosen remaining residue and then mineral spirits to prepare surface for painting. Surface should be completely clean and dry before refinishing.” My concern now is that I’ve made things worse because there are some spots where it did dry, about the size of a dime. (I don’t know how to reply and use paragraph breaks, sorry.)

Comment: @KFitz, the Comments system in SE is deliberately limited as to character count, and no paras are possible so don't sweat it :-) OK, so they do recommend MS, in that case follow their advice and see how you get on — the key thing would seem to be "completely clean and dry before refinishing" (definitely good advice), but, if you don't want to then use something else to clean the MS residue from the wood, go one further and wait until you can't smell the MS any more, with your nose right on the wood. This is quite a bit beyond the point where it *seems* like it has all evaporated. [contd]

Comment: Next step, the sanding you're going to do anyway, will help further. Then the grain raising with water will highlight ahead of stain time any areas where the water has a tendency to bead. You can try to sand those areas further till it goes away and/or rinse with with DA, acetone/lacquer thinner (all good degreasers). *"some spots where it did dry, about the size of a dime"* Don't worry overtly about those, you can try the suggested MS wash and see if that does enough to get rid of them, if it doesn't there's a common tip in stripping for dry areas, just use fresh stripper. Usually works well.

Comment: @KFitz, and thank you so much! I appreciate the appreciation :-)

Comment: Oops, I misunderstood and already used isopropyl. I’m think I’ve gotten all of the stripper off (not as much as I thought). I did find a few small spots with finish still on. I know what you think about sanding as a stripping method (no), but I’m wondering if since these are very small and this piece has no veneers, all solid, if it would be okay to remove the last of it w/sanding. If not  no real big deal, I’ll do  it again. Again, many thanks for your help.

Comment: Isopropyl alcohol works similarly to DA, which is mostly ethanol. Either can work OK to lift stripper residue (which more than likely consists of dissolved finish and the wax from the stripper). Spot-sanding is risky since it can leave a noticeable low spot despite being careful, so I'd suggest trying on 1 spot and see how easily it comes off (it might, after being weakened by the stripper, but sometimes these remaining bits can be remarkably stubborn!). But you can spot-strip remaining finish in case that wasn't clear from anything you've read, let the Citristrip do most of the work for you.

Comment: If you'd like to try scraping instead of sanding to tackle individual spots, scraping is generally very effective and controllable, and far better than sanding as a result. You'll want to investigate various ways to scrape if you want to get into more furniture refurbs/refinishing (card scraper, paint scraper, sharp knives, razor blades). Sometimes you can scrape off all prior finish, requires effort but the whole process is dry :-) and in the absence of old-style methylene chloride strippers — the really effective, but slightly dangerous, ones — this is the fastest way to take off old finish.

Comment: I actually found more isolated spots of finish when I held a bright lamp up to the desk and viewed from a very low angle, so I think it’s best to just apply another coat of CS to the entire surface. I have seen those scrapers in use and want to try it before using any stripping products again. My hope for this piece is that I’ve not damaged it by overly aggressive sanding when I still thought sanding was mostly harmless  I remind myself this is really a learning experience and the desk is not a treasured piece.

Comment: A carbide steel scraper is what I’ve seen in a couple of videos. Next time, I’d like to try that first, before a stripper. I have a much older piece [that is more important to me than this] and it was so hard to strip. I don’t think a blade would have worked on it since the finish was very old and thinned in spots  but for this desk with some sort of clear finish on it, the CS worked well in the first pass, and that finish came off mostly easily. It reminded me of nail polish, and I think I probably could have used a scraper for the first round, kind of like chipped nail polish.

Comment: Yes the carbide strippers are one good option for heavy removal. The larger ones with the two-handed grips can be a bit of a blunt instrument, although that's definitely something that the user plays a part in since you can just slow down and use any tool with more finesse. P.S. carbide blades should last a long, long time as you might expect and while replacement blades are available they're not cheap, so I should mentioned that carbide is easily sharpenable with diamonds. If you want to get into that, cheap  diamond plates ($5 or less!) are freely available on AliExpress [contd]

Comment: ...and represent superb value for money. Despite how cheap they are the general quality seems to be fine, and they do last many years even in the workshops of regular users. My oldest one is 7 this year, and apparently unworn. Although they are cheap enough you can splurge and get a selection, only two or three are really necessary or desirable, one at the coarse end, nothing in between, and one or maybe two at the fine end. So a 180 or 240, and then a 1000, and IF you want a 3000 also (which I think is as fine as they go).

Comment: That’s great to know. I’m looking forward to trying the carbide scraper. Thanks so much for the info. Now, I need to back through older posts here to figure out what grit to sand the top of that desk with. My test spots look good with water based stain. I used 180 on those before staining, after raising the grain. They feel smooth now. Again, thank you so much.

Comment: You'll find most of the advice here to say the same  (correct) thing, that prior to stain application not to sand too finely. And yes, 180 is just about perfect most of the time. After raising the grain using something finer is generally appropriate, many use 320 or a little finer.

Comment: I got fed up with finding tiny islands of finish, so reapplied the citristrip, thinly, over the entire thing and covering with wax paper. I did not want to put it on as heavily as I have before for a few reasons, including that it’s got a lot of water in it, and it’s a miserable chore removing c-strip. Some people, sites that are not high on my credible list, use plastic wrap (and even leave overnight). I loathe wasting plastic and wax seemed fine. My plan was to leave the CS on for 2 hrs since that short period was enough to remove ~90% of the clear [mystery] finish. Well? It’s good to use

Comment: 2/2 … to use furniture that don’t have much value as learning experiences, right? I found a number of spots with what think is glue and maybe wood filler too after this 2nd coat of C-strip. The isopropyl was okay at removing the CS but freaking tedious. I had used vinegar on another piece a few months ago (per the less credible sites ) and it does work. It was faster and easier at getting into the tiny nooks and crannies and getting that horrid CS off. Of course, the grain is again raised, so I need to deal with that. I tested the water based mineax stain on the spots with what

Comment: I think is wood filler—it’s fine. No, it’s not a “gorgeous” effect, but it’s good enough for my purposes and as a learning experience. Mango takes a finish quite well, but the problem is the craftsmanship of the piece in general. The desk was cheap stuff, and once I got down to truly bare wood, after round 2 with CS, I saw all kinds of, well, flaws that can be expected with very cheap imported furniture from India. Now, I’m tempted to go over the whole thing again with acetone/acrylic nail remover to make sure every bit of everything applied to this junk is removed. It’s been a learning experi

Comment: ….learning experience, and the desk still is still useful, but will never be anything more than a very flawed piece. (Not sure if you want me to create a new questions for this?) I’m going to stain it and finish it anyway, and I’m happy enough with Minwax pecan test area I did on the underside. I did use two coats, though. I had zero problems with application, on and off within 2 minutes. Advice on acetone because I don’t trust that every bit of glue is gone? And sand after first coat of water based stain is fully dry? I’m using Watco Danish oil as finish. Just want this experiment done now.

Comment: Yeah things like this can be waaaay more complicated than the carefully 'curated' steps on websites, or the heavily edited video on YT, tend to show! All valuable experience though as you say.

Comment: OK so I'll try to tackle everything you asked about. If you suspect there are areas of glue on the surface then by all means use acetone on them; it should be possible to assess whether they'll interfere with staining when you wet the wood, as they'll be noticeably paler. It's risky to sand after stain has gone on (any kind of stain). It's best to avoid it if at all possible. If you have to do it go *very* lightly, with fine-ish paper (320 or higher) and use only the weight of your hand. Be especially careful on any raised areas, at edges and corners. But it's better to pre-raise the grain.

Comment: Oh and I should probably mention that you can expect to see a little of the stain come off onto your rags/paper towels as you apply the "Danish oil" and when when you're wiping the excess off, especially for the first coat. You're already used to all the details that get left out of guides right? So, quelle surprise, often staining guides don't mention this at all but it is actually quite normal.

Comment: Oh, gosh, yes, yes, yes, the ‘staining guides’ and the experts all over online—it’s a piece of cake! Just put this on, cover with plastic wrap, and you got this! I have already sanded too much, I can see that. The spots that I suspect are some kind of glue residue aren’t noticeably lighter, like you described. When i dud the test areas with stain and danish oil, I saw that, some stain coming off. I did four areas, each about 6 inches by 3, on the wood inside that did not have any finish on it. They all look good. But that wood hasn’t been glued and doused with citristrip, vinegar etc!

Comment: What I have found is spots where the wood had chunks missing. It’s certainly not the best wood they used for this $170 retail desk. Of course not. Chunks filled in with wood putty or filler, and where the pieces of wood are glued together, it’s like they had to use so much glue because the wood was missing small chunks or was cracked, etc. At this point, I don’t think staining it is a good idea. I’m pretty sure that defects, divots, waviness, are accentuated by stain. One of my test areas is

Comment: Done with the Watco danish oil only. I tried out the dark walnut. It was lighter than I wanted (which is why I then moved onto testing with the dark water based stain). But looking at that test spot then looking at all the defects that showed up, I think I’m better off just using the tinted Watco. I almost bought a nightstand made in a very similar way, from India, thinking I’d just, presto, switch things up and guve it a new look. Im so glad I didnt waste my time or money. This has been a valuable learning experience, yup.

Comment: Oh, and regarding Citristrip, that stuff has a lot, a lot, a lot of water in it. It lifted a veneer on an older piece that does mean something to me, and I’m pretty sure it caused some of this mango to swell, and I never left it on the mango more than two hours. It’s got two drawers and after each round of citristrip one of the drawers wouldn’t close. Letting it dry overnight, it did. Same thing second time. So it’s either/or/maybe the wood was not properly dried and the citristrip is loaded with water. That was another reasons

Comment: … another reason for not using plastic wrap. All over online, YT and other sites, these “experts” show this terrific hack! Cover with plastic wrap, leave it overnight, and it’s so easy! No, I suspect it can wreck wood that is vulnerable, like a 40-year-old veneer and cheaply constructed mango. I’ll never use it again. Maybe acetone is the better choice. Keep a tan blowing away from you, not sure, but citristrip, yuech.

Comment: We have to curtail this as the Comments here have gone on too long (I got the auto-prompt to avoid extended discussions). But yeah Citristrip is indeed full of water and this is an issue for a number of application – especially in combination with its slower action! But there are some saf**er** strippers (safer than methylene chloride) that aren't like Citristrip so all hope is not lost if you want to continue to do this kind of project periodically and want to strip (because scraping isn't appropriate for the piece).